# ¿Como actualizar una tabla despues de eliminar un dato?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy intentando hacer la **acción de eliminar** un registro de una tabla, creada con `javaScript`, a partir de los datos de un `array`. La tabla se crea sin problemas y la eliminación del dato del `array` funciona correctamente, el problema es al momento de querer visualizar el resultado.

Al querer mostrar la tabla actualizada me repite el `array` pero sin el dato eliminado los datos nuevamente, mostrando los datos anteriores junto con los datos del mismo array pero sin el dato eliminado

```js
let array = [{"id":1,"nombre":"Nombre1","ap1":"Apellido1", "ap2":"Apellido1"}, {"id":2,"nombre":"Nombre2","ap1":"Apellido2", "ap2":"Apellido22"}, {"id":3,"nombre":"Nombre3","ap1":"Apellido3", "ap2":"Apellido23"}];


createTable(array);

function createTable(arrayNombres) {
    let tbodyAlumno = document.getElementById("tbodyAlumnos");
    for (let index = 0; index < arrayNombres.length; index++) {
    
        var fila = document.createElement("tr");
        
        var celda = document.createElement('td');
        celda.textContent = arrayNombres[index].nombre;
        fila.appendChild(celda);
    
        var celda = document.createElement('td');
        celda.textContent = arrayNombres[index].ap1;
        fila.appendChild(celda);
        
        var celda = document.createElement('td');
        celda.textContent = arrayNombres[index].ap2;
        fila.appendChild(celda);
    
            var celda1 = document.createElement('td');
            var buttonDelete = document.createElement("button");
            buttonDelete.textContent = "Eliminar";
            buttonDelete.className = "btn waves-effect cyan buttonMargin";
            buttonDelete.onclick = ()=>eliminar(arrayNombres[index].id);
        
            var buttonUpdate = document.createElement("button");    
            buttonUpdate.textContent = "Actualizar";
            buttonUpdate.className = "buttonMargin btn waves-effect cyan ";
    
            
    
            celda1.appendChild(buttonUpdate);
            celda1.appendChild(buttonDelete);
            
            
            fila.appendChild(celda1);
        
    
        tbodyAlumno.appendChild(fila);
    }   
}

function eliminar(id) {
    console.log("se presiono eliminar-->"+id);
    array.splice(array.findIndex(i => i.id==id),1);
    createTable(array);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navbar.css">

<!-- color de lineas 26a69a -->

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\autor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/general.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <title>Registro de autores</title>
</head>

<body>
   
    <div class="section no-pad-bot">
        <div class="container">
            <br><br>
            <h1 class="header center orange-text"> Registro de Docentes</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- SubTitulo -->
    <div class=" center">
        <h5 class="header col s12 light">Informacion</h5>
    </div>
    <!-- Formulario -->
    <div class="container">
        <table >
            <thead>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Primer apellido</td>
                <td>Segundo apellido</td>
                <td>Opciones</td>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbodyAlumnos">
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.js"></script>
    <script src="Js/crateTableAlumnos.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No solo no te esta actualizando el resultado del array, si no que ademas te esta duplicando la tabla.

Te falta vaciar la tabla antes de volverla a crear, lo puedes hacer del siguiente modo:

```
while (tbodyAlumno.firstChild) {
    tbodyAlumno.removeChild(tbodyAlumno.firstChild);
}
```

**NOTA:** Se puede vaciar tambien con `.innerHTML = '';` pero como se puede ver [en el siguiente hilo en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3955238/11463270), no elimina los nodos de forma "real" por lo que puede acabar dando problemas de rendimiento

```js
let array = [{"id":1,"nombre":"Nombre1","ap1":"Apellido1", "ap2":"Apellido1"}, {"id":2,"nombre":"Nombre2","ap1":"Apellido2", "ap2":"Apellido22"}, {"id":3,"nombre":"Nombre3","ap1":"Apellido3", "ap2":"Apellido23"}];


createTable(array);

function createTable(arrayNombres) {
    let tbodyAlumno = document.getElementById("tbodyAlumnos");
    while (tbodyAlumno.firstChild) {
        tbodyAlumno.removeChild(tbodyAlumno.firstChild);
    }
    for (let index = 0; index < arrayNombres.length; index++) {
    
        var fila = document.createElement("tr");
        
        var celda = document.createElement('td');
        celda.textContent = arrayNombres[index].nombre;
        fila.appendChild(celda);
    
        var celda = document.createElement('td');
        celda.textContent = arrayNombres[index].ap1;
        fila.appendChild(celda);
        
        var celda = document.createElement('td');
        celda.textContent = arrayNombres[index].ap2;
        fila.appendChild(celda);
    
            var celda1 = document.createElement('td');
            var buttonDelete = document.createElement("button");
            buttonDelete.textContent = "Eliminar";
            buttonDelete.className = "btn waves-effect cyan buttonMargin";
            buttonDelete.onclick = ()=>eliminar(arrayNombres[index].id);
        
            var buttonUpdate = document.createElement("button");    
            buttonUpdate.textContent = "Actualizar";
            buttonUpdate.className = "buttonMargin btn waves-effect cyan ";
    
            
    
            celda1.appendChild(buttonUpdate);
            celda1.appendChild(buttonDelete);
            
            
            fila.appendChild(celda1);
        
    
        tbodyAlumno.appendChild(fila);
    }   
}

function eliminar(id) {
    console.log("se presiono eliminar-->"+id);
    array.splice(array.findIndex(i => i.id==id),1);
    createTable(array);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navbar.css">

<!-- color de lineas 26a69a -->

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\autor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/general.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <title>Registro de autores</title>
</head>

<body>
   
    <div class="section no-pad-bot">
        <div class="container">
            <br><br>
            <h1 class="header center orange-text"> Registro de Docentes</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- SubTitulo -->
    <div class=" center">
        <h5 class="header col s12 light">Informacion</h5>
    </div>
    <!-- Formulario -->
    <div class="container">
        <table >
            <thead>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Primer apellido</td>
                <td>Segundo apellido</td>
                <td>Opciones</td>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbodyAlumnos">
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.js"></script>
    <script src="Js/crateTableAlumnos.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```